# Radiobutton value is None

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I am making a data entry window in Tkinter, and the window has the "Sex" option, but I'm having trouble determining which sex is selected.
My code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

data_list = []

class Personal_Data:

    def __init__ (self, sex, age, height, weight):

        self.sex = sex
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

def save_data (sex, age, height, weight, screen):

    screen.destroy ()
    data = Personal_Data (sex, age, height, weight)
    data_list.append (data)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo ("", "Entry saved!")

def data_entry ():

    data_entry_screen = Tk ()
    Label (data_entry_screen, text = "Sex:").grid (row = 0, column = 0)
    var = StringVar ()
    def sel ():
        print var.get ()
    male_pick = Radiobutton (data_entry_screen, text = "Male", variable = var, value = "Male", command = sel)
    male_pick.grid (row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "W")
    female_pick = Radiobutton (data_entry_screen, text = "Female", variable = var, value = "Female", command = sel)
    female_pick.grid (row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "E")
    sex = var.get ()
    Label (data_entry_screen, text = "Age:").grid (row = 1, column = 0)
    age_entry = Entry (data_entry_screen)
    age_entry.grid (row = 1, column = 1)
    Label (data_entry_screen, text = "Height:").grid (row = 2, column = 0)
    height_entry = Entry (data_entry_screen)
    height_entry.grid (row = 2, column = 1)
    Label (data_entry_screen, text = "Weight:").grid (row = 3, column = 0)
    weight_entry = Entry (data_entry_screen)
    weight_entry.grid (row = 3, column = 1)
    Button (data_entry_screen, text = "SAVE", command = lambda: \
            save_data (sex, age_entry.get(), height_entry.get(),\
                              weight_entry.get(), data_entry_screen)\
            ).grid (row = 4, column = 0)
    Button (data_entry_screen, text = "CANCEL", command = \
            data_entry_screen.destroy).grid (row = 4, column = 1)
root = Tk ()
root.title ("Main menu")
main_menu = Menu (root)

data_entry_menu = Menu (main_menu, tearoff = 0)
main_menu.add_cascade (label = "Data", menu = data_entry_menu)
data_entry_menu.add_command (label = "Data entry", command = data_entry)

root.config (menu = main_menu)

root.mainloop ()
```

Actually, the value it returns is None (I can see the returned value printed with the `sel` function), but I don't know why... Any ideas?

P.S. Sorry for the long code, but it's killing me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where `sex` is the value `None`, but I do see where it's the empty string, `''`. You are doing `sex = var.get()` immediately on creating and setting up the new window (which should be done with `Toplevel()`, by the way, not another root object). Since it wasn't `set()` at that point, it's the empty string, `''`. Changing the chosen value of that button later on doesn't affect that saved value. Instead, remove `sex = var.get()` and retrieve the radio button's value only when the "SAVE" button is clicked, like you are already doing with all the other entered data:

```
...save_data(var.get(), age_entry.get(),...
```

Comment: that did it, changed the `data_entry_screen = Tk ()` into `data_entry_screen = Toplevel ()`, and removed the `sex = var.get ()`, retrieved it's value with the `save_data (var.get ()...)...`